# cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for :: AdMob :: createBannerView

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I try to install & configure admob-free cordova plugin with ionic but I always have this error when banner.prepare() function is executed.

```
 this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
 }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

> cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for :: AdMob ::
>   createBannerView

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

- Ionic version: 3.20

Cordova version:

- android 7.0.0
- browser 5.0.3